# Are there any limitations on images used in iOS App

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval

I have read `IOS Human interface guide` and nothing much was said about iOS images. Are there any limitations like that images used in app should not have rounded corners or they cannot be circular. Also if I use an image to navigate to next page, is that image considered as an icon?

A detailed answer would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about an app store's policies and procedures, rather than programming. See [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The human interface guidelines are going to talk more about when to use an image, not how it's actually done. It sounds like you're ready to move on to more programming related samples.

To answer your actual question, no, there is no limitation on the shape of an image, but it's going to be treated as square in iOS--just as it is in the program that saved it. Transparencies will be respected.

There are many ways to navigate to another page. Many can use images. You might start with a button, as described [here](http://www.idev101.com/learn/adding_images.html). If you want to explore all of the ways to move from one view to another, a good beginner book on iOS programming may be in order. I found an earlier version of [Beginning iPhone Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1484204107) very helpful when I was learning iOS programming.

Comment: Greatly appreciate your answer. The very first paragraph cleared my mind of a lot of confusion. I agree with what you said about moving to programming related samples. I have been looking into shape,mask and gradient animations and completely got confused as after animation they are not flat images but images of various shapes as I compared images to icons. I like to clarify what will happen if I chose to use an icon instead of image in my app that whether I still need to follow the guidelines.

Comment: If I understand what you are asking correctly, an icon generally is an image. There are some built-in ones, or you can supply your own, but they are images. I say "generally" because it is possible to draw a button programmatically. The user can't tell the difference, but technically it would not be an image loaded from an image file.

Comment: Appreciate your quick response.I am designing app where user can select a fruit from list of given fruits and I was wondering whether that fruit is considered as icon or image as I need to display that fruit in the next navigated page for future use. So if I am not wrong that fruit icon or image can be glossy image with rounded corners.

Comment: It's an image. It may be best simply to forget the term icon, sicne it is immaterial at the Xcode level. In Xcode, the image is present as a supporting file that can easily be used in different places. Whether the various bottoms or other objects you use the image in share the image or not is really up to the implementation of those objects, and not something you should care much about, since in most cases you can't really tell anyway.